# Manually add dependencies to gradle cache

Tags: android, gradle, caching

I´m having an Android Studio project and the gradle build keeps failing with the message, that the caches might be corrupt and I should re-download them and sync. Had the same issue already a while ago and solved it by using a local gradle distribution (manually downloaded), now the issue seems to be produced by the kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4 and fast-util-7.2.0.jar. Everytime I try to build it takes 15 minutes to download that stuff and then tells me it´s corrupt and starts downloading these two dependencies again.
Since it is driving me crazy, I just want to manually download the files and add them to my cache to make sure they safely arrive in the gradle cache. I know, that it´s not the best solution to do it manually, but I don´t have by all means a stable internet connection here and there´s no possibility to get one either.
However I checked out some similar questions on SO and found out that it does not work to only add the jar to the caches folder. So, how do I do it then?
Other questions only have answers that require a local repository or a stable internet connection.